# The list<entity> in entity is not populated properly having Many to one mapping.

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i have an entity in which i have a list.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "subject_group_join",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name="sub_group_id")           
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name="subject_id")
    }
  ) 
List<SubjectEntity> listOfSubjects;
```

The Subject entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subject_details")
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GET_SUBJECT_BY_CLASS",query = "call fetchAllSubjectByClass(:classId,:sessionId)",resultClass = SubjectEntity.class)   ,
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GET_OPTIONAL_SUBJECT_BY_CLASS",query = "call fetchOptionalSubjectByClass(:classId,:sessionId)",resultClass = SubjectEntity.class),
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GET_CUMPULSORY_SUBJECT_BY_CLASS_NOT_GROUPED",query = "call fetchAllCumpulsorySubjectByClassNotGrouped(:classId,:sessionId)",resultClass = SubjectEntity.class),
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GET_OPTIONAL_SUBJECT_BY_CLASS_NOT_GROUPED",query = "call fetchAllOptionalSubjectByClassNotGrouped(:classId,:sessionId)",resultClass = SubjectEntity.class),
})
public class SubjectEntity extends AbstractEntity{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 7320078093064615396L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="subject_id")
private long subjectId;


@Column(name="subject_name",length=32)
private String subjectName;


@Column(name="subject_code",length=32)
private String subjectCode;


@Column(name="description",length=512)
private String description;


@Column(name="subject_status")
private boolean subjectStatus;
```

when i fetch the first entity list by Hql "from entity1";
it does not come up with all the data populated in subjectEntity it just have id in it.

Comment: change the title it should be `ManyToMany` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to find problem  but `ManyToMany` should look like somthing below

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="EMP_PROJ",
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private List<Project> projects;
```

Where `referencedColumnName` in your case will be name of the primary key column.

You can use [ManyToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany) For reference.